# What does "truth is fungible" mean?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

I've come across on more than one occasion this aphorism if you will that "truth is fungible". However I'm unsure about what that means because *fungible* refers to the exchangeablity of a currency or assets that are like-for-like.

Can anyone shed some light here?

Comment: Does [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fungible) help? *3 readily changeable to adapt to new situations.*

Answer (score 2):

One of the meanings of *fungible* is 'readily changeable to adapt to new situations : flexible' ([Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fungible).)

The phrase *truth is fungible* means that truth is, at least to an extent, not absolute, and can be made to be whatever one wants it to be.

Examples of usage:

> *To Wild, **truth is fungible,** and reality should bend to him.*
>
> <sup>From *Approaches to Teaching the Novels of Henry Fielding.* United States: Modern Language Association of America, 2015. [(link)](https://books.google.com/books?id=AnCADwAAQBAJ&pg=PT195&dq=%22truth+is+fungible%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjxz8HtqpzuAhV-EVkFHY6GDvwQ6AEwAHoECAAQAg)</sup>
>
> *Some invoke the indeterminacy of quantum mechanics to suggest that **truth is fungible**.*
>
> <sup>From Shirk, Jr Willis L. *A History of the Atomic Space Age and Its Implications for the Future.* United States: Dog Ear Publishing, 2018. [(link)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/A_History_of_the_Atomic_Space_Age_and_It/qXdLDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22truth%20is%20fungible%22&pg=PA134&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22truth%20is%20fungible%22)</sup>
>
> *For such people, “remorse” is a word in a foreign dictionary. **Truth is fungible** and deceit is the norm.*
>
> <sup>From Dimsdale, Joel E. *Anatomy of Malice: The Enigma of the Nazi War Criminals.* United Kingdom: Yale University Press, 2016. [(link)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Anatomy_of_Malice/hK8ODAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22truth%20is%20fungible%22&pg=PT217&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22truth%20is%20fungible%22)</sup>
>
> *It is a universe where **truth is fungible** and moral conviction a mere asset, like good looks or personal wealth, a universe where corporeal restraints do not exist and people regularly become things they are not.*
>
> <sup>From Mandery, Evan. *Eyes On City Hall: A Young Man's Education In New York City Political Warfare.* United States: Taylor & Francis, 2018. [(link)](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Eyes_On_City_Hall/MHhQDwAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22truth%20is%20fungible%22&pg=PT9&printsec=frontcover&bsq=%22truth%20is%20fungible%22)</sup>

Comment: Please don't bury citations in the single word "source". [Citations must appear in full in plain text](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing), linked if possible (as you have here).

Comment: These examples are all illustrations of not accepting truth as truth. They thus reveal moral defect or a disconnect with reality. So this answer is misleading.

Comment: @Xanne In the second example, there is no implication of moral deficit or disconnect with reality. And even if there were, so that there is such an implication in all of the examples, note that in all of the examples (in which it exists), such implication is gathered from the context rather than directly from the phrase. So I don't see why the definition as given is misleading.

Comment: @Xanne Given that Truth is immutable, to say it's fungible is paradoxical at best. That doesn't invalidate the answer, which explains what *fungible truth* is. This isn't Philosophy.SE.